# How can I execute `git tfs rcheckin` from TortoiseGit like a `push`?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-tfs

I'm using Git and TortoiseGit locally under Windows against a Team Foundation Server with Team Foundation Version Control (not Git!).

When working with [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) against a Git server it's pretty easy to pull, fetch, and push. But using [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/) I need for every push, pull or fetch to go to the command line and perform the associated `git tfs ...` commands. Although they can easily be covered by Windows `.cmd` files, I'm looking for a possibility to work with the TortoiseGit GUI as well.

Is there any possibility to add the TFS remote in `.git` like `[remote "origin"]`? Entries line `[tfs-remote "default"]` already exist, but are not used by TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to add the TFS remote in .git like [remote "origin"]?

No. that's not possible to treat a `git tfs push` as a simple git remote. The had the idea when I was actively developing `git-tfs` in the past but concluded it didn't worth the effort.

> I'm looking for a possibility to work with the TortoiseGit GUI as well.

I don't know if it's possible to run custom command from TortoiseGit.
But I know that it is easily done with another GUI [GitExtensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) with the feature called [Scripts](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#git-extensions-scripts).

I made it in the past to ... use git-tfs ;)

PS: and personally, I find that GitExtensions is a better GUI than TortoiseGit as it better reflect how git is working (TortoiseGit has some remaining influences of it's TortoiseSvn father ;) )

Comment: I'll have a look into GitExtensions as well, thanks for the tip!